# How to fill down only specific values in a row when the number of entries to fill may vary

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, if-statement, na

I have the following code and I only want to fill down column c if it is 86 and the same value for column a (A, B, or C).

Is there a way using for-loop/if-else statements to fill downwards only certain values if the number of NAs may vary?

```
#Create a dataframe
a <- c('A','A','A','A','B','B','B','C','C','C','C')
b <- c(NA,NA,86,NA,NA,88,NA,NA,86,NA,NA)

df <- data.frame(a,b)
df
```

Desired output:

```
#Create a dataframe
a <- c('A','A','A','A','B','B','B','C','C','C','C')
b <- c(NA,NA,86,86,NA,88,NA,NA,86,86,86)

df <- data.frame(a,b)
df
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### If else with indexing

First create a copy of `df` (saved as `tmp` in my code).

If the previous row is `NA` and the current row is also `NA`, **or** if the previous row is `NA` but the current row isn't, set the value as the original `df` value.

Finally, if column `a` in previous row match column `a` in current row, **and** previous row equals 86, set the row to 86.

```r
tmp <- df

for (i in 2:nrow(df)) {
  if (is.na(tmp[i - 1, 2]) & !is.na(tmp[i, 2]) | is.na(tmp[i - 1, 2]) & is.na(tmp[i, 2])) {
    tmp[i, 2] <- df[i, 2] 
  } else if (tmp[i - 1, 1] == tmp[i, 1] & tmp[i - 1, 2] == 86) {
    tmp[i, 2] <- 86
  }
}


tmp
   a  b
1  A NA
2  A NA
3  A 86
4  A 86
5  B NA
6  B 88
7  B NA
8  C NA
9  C 86
10 C 86
11 C 86
```

### Original dplyr solution

You can create a temporary copy of column `b`, and `fill` that `tmp` column in a downward fashion. Then change anything not "86" back to it's original value in column `b`.

```r
library(dplyr)

df |> 
  group_by(a) |> 
  mutate(tmp = b) |> 
  fill(tmp, .direction = "down") |> 
  mutate(b = ifelse(tmp == 86, tmp, b), .keep = "unused")

# A tibble: 11 × 2
# Groups:   a [3]
   a         b
   <chr> <dbl>
 1 A        NA
 2 A        NA
 3 A        86
 4 A        86
 5 B        NA
 6 B        88
 7 B        NA
 8 C        NA
 9 C        86
10 C        86
11 C        86
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you can try `replace` like below

```
df %>%
    mutate(
        b = replace(b, seq_along(b) > which(b == 86) & is.na(b), 86),
        .by = "a"
    )
```

which gives

```
   a  b
1  A NA
2  A NA
3  A 86
4  A 86
5  B NA
6  B 88
7  B NA
8  C NA
9  C 86
10 C 86
11 C 86
```

Comment: I know there must be a one-liner for this but cannot figure it out myself! +1! BTW earlier the OP requested a solution that uses for loop, indexing and if statements in the comment (now deleted).

Comment: @benson23 yes, I saw you already provided a loop/ifelse solution, so I don't think I need to rebuild the wheel :P